# Tracking list aging

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

My program periodically receives a list of items, let's make them fruit. So the first list might look like this:

```
[apple, pear, banana]
```

A two more lists:

```
[pear, banana, plum, mandarin]
[banana, plum, apple]
```

What I want is a data structure that holds all the items in the most recent list and how many consecutive times each item has appeared. The end state here should be:

```
[banana:3, plum:2, apple:1]
```

because banana has been there in the last three lists, plum just the last two and apple is a new entry (despite the fact we saw it a while ago we forgot about it because it wasn't there last time).

The obvious way (and the way our software does it) is to:

```
foreach(Fruit f in oldList){
    f.old = true;
}

foreach(Fruit newF in newList){
    foreach(Fruit oldF in oldList){
        if(newF == oldF){
            oldF.old = false;
            oldF.count++;
        }
    }
}

// iterate through oldList to remove all old entries
oldList.Remove((x) => x.old);
```

But this is a lot of looping and is becoming a bottle neck as the program handles more data. Can this be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

The given solution is O(n<sup>2</sup>). If you *sort* the two lists together, then merge and delete fruit, it's O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to get a performance increase here is to do the removal of no longer needed fruit before checking to increase the count - it would mean less iterations of the inner loop.

However a better solution would be to sort (or if possible- originally store) the fruit in a known order; doing this would remove the need for the inner loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in O(n) (the theoretically optimal asymptotic complexity you can get for this problem) if you use a HashMap. If you don't worry about creating new objects, the cleanest solution would be to just do this. The code below is in Java but I think it's easy enough to understand.

```
public final class ConsistentFruitCountMaintainer {
        private Map<String, Integer> fruitToCount = new HashMap<>();

        public void processList(final List<Fruit> fruits) {
            final Map<String, Integer> nextMap = new HashMap<>();
            for(final Fruit fruit : fruits) {
                if (fruitToCount.containsKey(fruit)) {
                    nextMap.put(fruit, fruitToCount.get(fruit) + 1);
                } else {
                    nextMap.put(fruit, 1);
                }
            }
            fruitToCount = nextMap;
        }

        public Map<Fruit, Integer> getCurrentCounts() {
            return new HashMap<>(fruitToCount);
        }
    }
```